# How to backup the whole machine in google cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have several instances with more than one disk each.
We want to clone/backup the whole machine so we can start it when needed.

I know that I can create snapshots from the disks, but this is not a very good solution when you have many machines with 2+ disks. (taking snapshots of each disk and then looking up for all the disks when trying to re-create the machine is not straight forward)
Is there some way like in AWS to backup/image/clone the whole machine?

It doesn't have to be via gui/web as we intend to use it with ansible, or a script.

Thank You,
Maxim.

Comment: Would a script that lists the disks on an instance, and that creates a snapshot for each one be sufficient?  In Powershell?

Comment: Did you mean the native GCP tools or you can consider any third party applications?

Answer (score 0):

What about using some usual backup tools e.g.Cloudberry or some other of the kind? They have various versions and are able to backup both locally and in the cloud.I know that Cloudberry can create the disk snapshots what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the gcloud interactive shell for scripting the backup of your virtual machines. The gcloud shell is part of the Google Cloud SDK. Its very well documented. See this link on how to access your virtual machine disks from gcloud shell: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/

Comment: this does not answer the OP question.